# Where do I set character encoding in SOAPUI Preferences

Tags: character-encoding, soapui

I can't seem to find any `character encoding` options in `SoapUI` preferences.

I want to mock xml response in `iso-8859-1` encoding.

Comment: Very good question: in particular, because Soapui tries to send JSON in something else but UTF-8 on my system, although anything else but UTF-8 is invalid for JSON.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To set up an encoding for request/response you have to mark it in Navigator. Then in the view under the navigator go to "Request/Response properties" choose encoding and set i.e. to UTF-8 or iso-8859-1.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

You may choose either of the following approach.

**Changing the defualt encoding**

1. Go to SOAPUI_HOME/bin.
2. Open soapui.bat/.sh, depending on your platform.
3. You should be able find `JAVA_OPTS`, then you can add there below line in a new line
   `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding="iso-8859-1"` on windows
   `export JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding="iso-8859-1"` on unix
4. Save the file, start `SoapUI`.

It should take default encoding as `iso-8859-1`.

**Alternatively, message specific:**

Otherwise, you may use message specific character encoding using `http headers`for that specific one in the following way:

Set a new header for request / response.
**Header Key/name:**`Content-Type`
**Header Value :**`text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: For those trying this out and it doesn't work, SmartBear changed things around a bit. The file that needs to be edited is `SoapUI-5.#.#.vmoptions` (replacing # with your Version). Add the line `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` (Note without "") **before** the line `-splash:SoapUI-Spashscreen.png`. Do that and it will work as described in this answer.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but the accepted answer doesn't work for me, I'm in Windows10, in my case I update the `SoapUI-5.6.0\bin\SoapUI-5.6.0.vmoptions` file, add a new JVM arguments:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Then restart the SOAP-UI, the response can return the correct content(e.g. with some special characters like `®`)

Answer (score 1):

if you have windows
 1-  Open NotePad++ as a admin
   Go to path  C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin
  open soapui.bat and search for

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.library.path="%SOAPUI_HOME%\"
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dwsi.dir="%SOAPUI_HOME%..\wsi-test-tools"
*****set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding="iso-8859-1"*****
```

Add the last line above set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding="iso-8859-1" by taking the *****  out.

Save and restart SOAPUI