# SoapUI window freeze

Tags: soapui

Currently using SoapUI 5.2.1 and am experiencing random UI window freeze. This abnormality often occurs right after invoking a rest service. The said rest service(s) from previous and fresh boot invoke runs smooth, but after series of invoke(s) the whole SoapUI window freezes.

Any hints regarding this?

Comment: Yes, this is an unresolved problem with SoapUI.

Comment: Oh? How long have this been an issue?

Comment: I think I filed a defect with them sometime around version 4.2.

Comment: Are you on windows? Please post your `soapui-errors.log` (see Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin). I have similar problems but they usually come from plugins crashing

Comment: Have the same problems. Freeze on getting/render response from rest service.

Comment: I had the same problem. This may solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747109/where-do-i-set-character-encoding-in-soapui-preferences

Comment: I dont have any external plugins loaded/used. Its keeps freezing for me the moment i sent rest service call. Frustrated on this bug as i couldnt find a pattern or tell you when the freeze happens, i see no errors in logs as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you're sending a lot of requests via e.g. groovy, you'll want to discard the response on the request (this prevents out of memory problems which freezes soapui)

[image]

Note: You have to close the response window. If the response window is still open, you'll still see a response.

For more memory related settings see: https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/working-with-soapui/improving-memory-usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Open file "soapui.bat" in edit mode(It will be inside C:..\SoapUI-5.4.0\bin).
I have changed maximum memory that can be used to 2048 as below.
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx**2048**m
Then open soapUi by running batch file "soapui.bat". I not face any freeze after making this change.

Comment: I have this batch file as shortcut in my local. So I don't need to installation folder each time.

Answer (score 0):

I've started to run tests only from command line via /bin/testrunner because of this reason (it is pretty comfortable if you use groovy scripts). I use GUI of SoapUI only to manage REST resources, test suites and test cases.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to disable browser component

add `-Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true` into vmoptions file
or uncomment such line in the `soapui.bat`

Comment: Your solution not worked for me.  It still hangs when executing a single soap request (not always, as before).

Answer (score 0):

I worked some years using SoapUI and keeping the software update will help with some kind of problems. You won't lose your work if auto-save option in SoapUI Prefererences > UI Settings still enable.

I highly recommend 3 books about SoapUI:

Testing Web Services with SoapUI
[image: Testing Web Services with SoapUI]

SoapUI Cookbook
[image: SoapUI Cookbook]

Mastering SoapUI
[image: Mastering SoapUI]