# Issue with character encoding

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am currently facing issue with character encoding in soap webservice.
When ever I send request from SOAP UI

```
 <chgWho>Raj eěso</chgWho>
```

In logsrequest is displayed as

```
 chgWho=Raj e?so
```

How to encode the character set in the same way it was sent

Comment: what is `logsrequest`? is it a console output of response/request?

Comment: Console output of request..We are getting this special characters from request

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747109/where-do-i-set-character-encoding-in-soapui-preferences)?

Comment: I changed the format in Soap ui as mentioned in the above link..But it is not working.It is still printing the special characters as ?

Comment: You must check what is the suitable charset for these special character before set it in soap ui. What language are you using?

Comment: Java.It is the problem in the provider not from the consumer as i tried even i tried to call with java client code.Same thing is happening with that too.