# Junk characters in SoapUI DataSource -> SQL Query, how to handle this?

Tags: mysql, soapui

I need use Chinese Chars in SoapUI Pro [DataSource Step] - [Data Connection] SQL Query command, but it shows junk characters here and the query result is null, how to handle this issue?

The SQL Query as below:
SELECT id FROM configs_account WHERE NAME=TRIM("apitest_ValidData_使用中文作为名称");

[see screenshots for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9COrH.png)

Comment: Did you check encoding? Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747109/where-do-i-set-character-encoding-in-soapui-preferences) is relevant..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be solved by update editor font setting:

File -> Preferences -> Editor Settings

Editor Font = Microsoft YaHei UI Light